# Структура java-программы

Tags: java, ооп

Добрый день.
Я новичок в Java, в-целом занимаюсь программированием любительски, стараясь подниматься до профессионального уровня.
Можете подсказать как грамотно сделать структуру программы.

У меня есть классы:

- без пакета `MainClass` (точка входа в приложение)
- в пакете `gui`: `MainFrame extends JFrame` - отрисовка главного окна приложения
- `ImagePanel extends Jpanel` - отрисовка изображения
- в пакете `models`: `ImageByteArray` (хранит изображение в виде массива, методы для работы с ним)
- `Modem` - здесь будут производиться манипуляции с `ImageByteArray`.

Классы в `models` делаю так, чтобы мог перенести в другое приложение.

По нажатию кнопок меню в `MainFrame` буду формировать `ImageByteArray`, делать что-то с ним, возвращать обратно изображение из него.

**Вопрос:** где хранить обработчики событий меню? У меня есть вариант в `MainFrame`, но тогда код отрисовки окна смешивается с логикой манипуляцией данными, или в `MainClass`, так как в нем создаю `MainFrame`?

Comment: Поразмыслив , решил сделать так: сделать абстрактным MainFrame, сделать абстрактные методы protected abstract void initHandlers(), там реализовать обработчики, а в наследнике делать манипуляции данными.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте MVC.
Кроме того разберитесь что такое SRP (принцип единственной ответственности)

Исходя из этого разбейте Ваши классы по пакетам и директориям.
При этом если есть необходимость, то соответственно можно добавлять новые директории.
В любую из mvc директорий.
И ресурсы в отдельной директории resources.
Примерно так

```
[Proj dir]
 ├[src]
 │   ├[model]
 │   ├[view]
 │   └[controller]
 └[resources]
```

Comment: @Barmaley, А чем собственно он по вашему плох? Тем что позволяет отделить логику от гуя и от связывающего их контроллера?

Comment: Да нет он хорош, как идея, как лозунг типа: всем зарплату в 10 тыс. евро - но в реале это не работает, равно как и зарплату всем 10 тыс. евро - и даже 1000 евро не получается. А так все отлично - слоган замечательный, но нереализуемый.

Comment: Интересная у Вас логика, а есть реальное доказательство вашего утверждения?

Comment: Беда с MVC в том, что это детище 70-х годов, за 40 лет он уже устарел. Конечно он до сих пор держится в вебе, и то как только в код допустите ajax запросы - прощай MVC. В Android разработке - MVC и не пахло - там доминируют совсем другие концепты.

Comment: Если смотреть с этой точки зрения то он хоть и устарел (тут с Вами полностью согласен) но все еще функционален, а если посмотреть с другой стороны (простой, легко реализуемый, понятный новичку и профессионалу) то очень даже получается полезный.

Comment: А где хранить классы, отвечающие за ajax-запросы? Это ведь мост между controller и model?

Comment: @Barmaley не согласен, что в Android-разработке "MVC не пахло" - может и не в идеально чистом виде, но этот паттерн остается пока основным для взаимодействия с View (реализован через Model - данные, View - разметка, Controller - активити) и единственным, реализуемым через фреймворк.

Comment: @Barmaley Альтернативные решения  - через внешние библиотеки и сам гугл предлагает только MVVM (библиотека DataBinding) в более-менее юзабельном виде, так же совсем недавно запущена [альфа Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/guide.html), которая судя по всему тот же MVC, только в профиль. Остальные паттерны (MVP, MVI, MV..) - вообще сторонние решения со всеми вытекающими